# Animate collection instances respectively?

Tags: node-editor, animation-nodes

I'm trying to make a dynamic army using animation nodes now, and succeed in generating collection instances by nodes below. Now I want some variation on animation in these instances.

[image]

walking animation is set on the original collection and currently, the actions of all instances are synchronized.

I have struggled to make them move respectively but no avail so far. I'm pretty new to Animation Nodes.

I ask for your advice.

thanks

Comment: Hello, I don't think this is possible with collection instances. They are supposed to be exact copies of the instanced collection and apart from loc, rot, scale you can't change much between them. You should rather use linked duplicates and separate the animation data if it's possible

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Gorgious. I really appreciate your advice. I think the linked duplicates could do. I would try it right away. thanks again.